# Insert relational data in lookup table 

Tags: codeigniter, fuelcms

I am managing to construct a form (with FuelCMS) that has a look-up table, and the look-up table has a field that must be inserted at the same time as the relation (Figure 1).

Using a model inside my module I have finished the form to insert the data, I have a control (Figure 2) to select the relation between the two tables, and here is where my question comes. I need to show a pop-up (like the one when you press the "ADD" or "EDIT" button that allow the user to insert the value of the "objetivo" field (Figure 1) at the time you assign "Hitos" to the "indicadores".

What is the best way to do this? Can I attach a JS file to the form from the module to be able to capture the button click and show the pop-up? There are another better way already to achieve that task?

I hope I made my point clear, if not, please tell me and I will try to explain myself better.

Thanks :)

[image: DB Tables]
**Figure 1**

[image: FuelCMS admin]
**Figure 2**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the kind of the FuelCMS team I was at the end able to solve the situation I explained before, to achive the aim you should follow the next steps:

- Add a javascript file on the module config (fuel/modules/MODULE_NAME/config/MODULE_NAME_fuel_module.php)
- Use the Javascript hooks 'selectionAdded' and 'selectionRemoved' to launch the popup (FuelCMS uses [jqmodal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) as popup) the functions pass as a parameter an array "vals" that contains the ID of the selected items.
- Add a AJAX request in the popup code to retrive the form
- Process the form and keep the values for later saving on database or manipulatión.

It could be a bit tricky if you need a complex logic but is an effective way of do it :)

Once again TAHNKS to the FuelCMS support people, i hope this help someone.

Best regards.